# Unsuccessful error detection of improperly declared method in GCC 4.2 compiler

Tags: xcode, c++

I am using C++ compiler GCC 4.2 in XCode 3.2.2.  I have noted that the compiler will successfully compile a method foo even though there are no ellipses.  The header and method are properly declared as foo(), but when I do a find and replace either by file or by program-wide it will miss approximately 2-3% of the changes [foo to foo().  This would not be critical if the compiler did not give an erroneous successful build. I have not found that this occurs with: foo(any parameter).  Does anyone have any solution?  Thank you.

Comment: The ellipsis is the three dots ... - are you by any chance asking about parentheses i.e. ()? In either case, post some actual code that illustrates what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear from your question what you are actually asking about, but if it is function *calls* then:

```
void foo() {
}

int main() {
    foo();    // valid C++ - call foo
    foo;      // valid C++ - get  a function pointer
}
```

If you want a warning about the second use of foo, compile with the GCC `-Wall` flag (which you should really be using all the time in any case)  - this will give you:

```
f.cpp:6: warning: statement is a reference, not call, to function 'foo'
f.cpp:6: warning: statement has no effect
```

Comment: To add a GCC flag through xcode:

Go to the "Project" menu and select "Edit Project Settings"
Select the "Build" tab
Find the "Other C++ Flags" setting and double click on the blank space to the right
Click the plus sign and add "-Wall"

Answer (score 0):

To add a GCC flag through xcode:

1. Go to the "Project" menu and select "Edit Project Settings"
2. Select the "Build" tab
3. Find the "Other C++ Flags" setting and double click on the blank space to the right
4. Click the plus sign and add "-Wall"